# Sprite Kit: Prevent SKSpriteNode From Gliding Around

Tags: sprite-kit, osx-mavericks, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I'm working on a spaceship game for OS X using SpriteKit. This is how I setup `physicsBody` for my spaceship node.

```
// SKSpriteNode
ship.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:triangle];

ship.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
ship.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory | edgeCategory;
ship.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory | edgeCategory;

ship.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
ship.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
ship.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0;
ship.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.1;
ship.physicsBody.mass = 0.1;
ship.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
```

This is how I setup `physicsWorld` and `physicsBody` in my scene file.

```
// SKScene
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = edgeCategory;
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = missileCategory | enemyCategory | playerCategory;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory;

self.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
```

In my scene's `update` method, I call `[ship accelerate:@"up"];`, which ends up calling this.

```
[self.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(self.engineThrust * cosf(self.shipOrientation),
                                          self.engineThrust * sinf(self.shipOrientation))];
```

Is there a way to disable the ship's inertia? I don't want my ship gliding along my scene. I want the ship to stop moving as soon as I release the key. I also want the ship to immediately change direction when toggling between the up arrow and the down arrow.

Is there something in `physicsBody` that I can change or will I have to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop any inertia by using `ship.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0);`

Comment: I tried adding that as the first line in my accelerate method, but it really screws up the way the ship moves. That's not a good place to put it.

Comment: @425nesp - Not sure what you mean by that. Setting the velocity to 0,0 stops all x and y axis movement.

Comment: I ended up doing `ship.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)` in the `update` function, right before calling `[ship accelerate:@"up"]`. I also turned up the `engineThrust` way up, otherwise, the ship barely moves.